# Move object along path in html canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, path

I have a path in which I'd like to move a circle. 
After the circle has completed moving along the path it should disappear.

[image]

And for the animation of the circle I'm using the requestAnimationFrame() method in the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate a DOM object along a path using CSS, you need to learn about the CSS Motion Path module - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Motion_Path

Similaraly, to animate an object along a path in an SVG object, you need to come to terms with the SVG <animateMotion> element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion

Achieving a similar result in a <canvas> element requires a lot of work. You need to create your path, then map out coordinates along that path as time progresses, then draw your circle at the appropriate coordinate each RequestAnimationFrame. It is do-able, though you probably want to make your life easier with the help of a canvas and/or animation library.

- GreenSock GSAP has a MotionPath plugin which you should be able to use to get coordinates along a path which, in turn, you can use for drawing your circle on the canvas - https://greensock.com/motionpath/
- Scrawl-canvas [disclaimer: I wrote this library] makes animating things along a path as simple as possible. See this CodePen for demo code - https://codepen.io/kaliedarik/pen/MWadEwm

  Example code:

  ```
    scrawl.makePolyline({
        name: 'my-polyline',
        pins: [[10, 10], ['20%', '90%'], [120, 'center']],
        mapToPins: true,
        method: 'draw',
    });
  ```